# fill in content creation form based on view

Tags: views, nodes, forms

I have 2 different types of content for users that rely on each other called goals and tasks. The way I have the system set up is that each task must be a part of a goal and this is the view I have set up (through nested accordions):
[image]
What I want to do is add a link inside of each goal accordion that says add task and will make a block appear on the screen of this node creation form:
[image]

Except that I want the Goal field (which is an entity reference field) to automatically be filled in with the goal that was clicked, and I want the student field to be filled in with the name of the logged in user. My question is if there is a module that can do this, or are there any other ways to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.